# How to dynamically add and delete rows in table through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have written some code but I need that the new row will inserted at the last row not on the top.

```
function insertRow(){
   var x=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(0);
   var y=x.insertCell(0);
   var z=x.insertCell(1);
   var d=x.insertCell(2);
   y.innerHTML="NEW CELL1";
   z.innerHTML="NEW CELL2";
   d.innerHTML='<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';
}

function deleteRow(r){
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}
```

[**Demo at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/prakashup/J6zd3/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(-1);`

-1 adds in last position